# Matplotlib Slider Labels stop responding with very small numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm creating a few sliders on python using matplotlib, and a few of the sliders I need to have will have ranges that are quite small (such as a range from 10E-15 to 10E-8, etc.). However, when I try to get those values to show up on the slider, it stops working. The slider rectangle will still show up on the plot, and I am able to "slide" the numbers around, but it's not showing up in the little text to the side where it shows what number the slider is at. 
[As you can see in this picture, it's just stuck on '0.00'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukmtR.png)

I suspect it's because the display only shows decimal values to two places, but I don't know how to increase the number of decimal places shown. Is there a parameter in the Slider function I can use to change that? Any help would be appreciated, I am still pretty new to using Python (only a couple of weeks, in fact) so an explanation in simple terms would be very appreciated.

Here is an example of the code I used to make one of such sliders.

```
a2 = 4.721*(math.pow(10,-11))
a2_size = plt.axes([0.4, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05], facecolor = axcolor) # left, bottom, width, height
a2_slider = Slider(a2_size, 'A2', valmin=math.pow(10,-15), valmax=math.pow(10,-10), valinit=a2)
```

(I've also tried alternating between math.pow and just using the ** multiplier, but it had the same effect.)
 Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your version of matplotlib since, for me, the code

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
a2 = 4.721*(math.pow(10,-11))
a2_size = plt.axes([0.4, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05], facecolor = axcolor) # left, bottom, width, height
a2_slider = Slider(a2_size, 'A2', valmin=math.pow(10,-15), valmax=math.pow(10,-10), valinit=a2)
plt.show()
```

appears like this
[image: Everything is working and the notation is suitable for the values of the slider]

However, you can use `valfmt` to format the value of the slider, use something like `%0.9e` which will make the value like this
[image: The value format converted into scientific notation]

So, the final code will look something like this

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
a2 = 4.721*(math.pow(10,-11))
a2_size = plt.axes([0.4, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05], facecolor = axcolor) # left, bottom, width, height
a2_slider = Slider(a2_size, 'A2', valmin=math.pow(10,-15), valmax=math.pow(10,-10), valinit=a2, valfmt='%0.9e')
plt.show()
```